# Undefined function or variable matlab cell2mat?

Tags: matlab, variables

When I load my function I created to a new file it does not recognize my variable. I'm trying to turn my cell array to a matrix using cell2mat. So what do i need to do to recognize the variable? Pictures are on thee bottom as well

```
file1
%Name function
function [name, hw, mt, fe]=enter_grades(number)
%inputs are scores outputs are there name and scores on hw mt fe
%asks for name and scores and stores them
ca = cell(number,4);
for i = 1:number
name = input('Enter names  of students! : ', 's');
hw = input('Enter Homework grade 0-100! : ', 's');
mt = input('Enter Midterm Exam grade 0-100! : ', 's');
fe = input('Enter Final Exam grade 0-100! : ', 's');
ca(i,:)={name hw mt fe};
end
save('enter_grades.mat', 'ca');
end
% this is used to call function
%[name, hw, mt, fe]=enter_grades(2)

file2

%Name function
function [avg, fg]=calc_stats(data)
%inputs is data from enter_grades outputs are there name and scores on hw mt fe
%creat an array that store all the grades and calculate the final grade
data=load('enter_grades.mat','ca')
a=cell2mat(ca)

end
```

[image: file1]
[image: file2]

I have changed the a=cell2mat(data.ca) now i get this.

```
Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in cell2mat (line 78)
        m = cat(1,m{:});

Error in calc_stats (line 6)
a=cell2mat(data.ca);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use [`load` with an output argument](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html#btm3ohm-1), the requested variables to load are stored as fields on an output structure.  So your code should be:

```
data=load('enter_grades.mat','ca');
a=cell2mat(data.ca);
```

---

I'd also note that this is a best practice when using Matlab's `load`.  To quote someone who [blogs for MathWorks](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2012/01/13/best-practices-for-programming-matlab/):

> Don't "poof" variables into any workspaces. Translation, **don't use load without a left-hand side**; avoid eval, evalin, and assignin.

(*The added emphasis is mine.*)

So kudos are in order. ... Kudos!

Comment: Alright I changed that now im getting a new error.                                            Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in cell2mat (line 78)
        m = cat(1,m{:});

Error in calc_stats (line 6)
a=cell2mat(data.ca);

Comment: @JTBlackstad To me, that says the strings you created in `enter_grades` are not of equal length.  If that is the case, leave `data.ca` as a cell array; that's, in my opinion, the best way to handle unequal length strings.

Comment: So I want to turn it to a matrix so i can put the values into an equation to compute average grades. i noticed since the grade could be 1 10 or 100 that is why im getting the unequal error and length of the name could also throw that off?

Comment: @JTBlackstad If you know the data being entered is numeric, define `ca` to be numeric (`ca = zeros(number,4)`) and either remove `'s'` from all of the inputs or assign to `ca` like this `ca(i,:)=str2double({name hw mt fe});'.  Either of these will make the data numeric and more easily concatenable.